# How can I read a xml Response from T-SQL?

Tags: xml, web-services, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have this Store Procedure to call and read the response from a web service. I call a Web services from store procedure.
I have a problem when I try to read the response. So the code is this:

```
SET @Response=
    '
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <soap:Body>
            <RegisterUserResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
                <RegisterUserResult>DRnGXcT2gFTTxta4+ohnVx30Q1UL7N8gUqx0zpYMtMqmgwhkHmmXRWSoHu+Ghk0x</RegisterUserResult>
            </RegisterUserResponse>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>'

    declare @iXDoc int
    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @iXDoc OUTPUT, @Response

    select *
    from openxml(@iXDoc, '/Envelope/Body/RegisterUserresponse/RegisterUserResult',2)
```

I have a empty result. If I try to change the query in

```
select *
        from openxml(@iXDoc, '',2)
```

I have the result but it is not ok for me.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML has two namespaces that matter; `soap` namespace declared at the root element and default namespace declared at `<RegisterUserResponse>` element. So you need to pass namespace prefixes mapping as parameter for `sp_xml_preparedocument` :

```
declare @nsmap varchar(200) = '<root xmlns:d="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>'
declare @iXDoc int
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @iXDoc OUTPUT, @Response, @nsmap
```

and then use the mapped prefixes properly in the xpath :

```
select *
from openxml(@iXDoc, '/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/d:RegisterUserResponse/d:RegisterUserResult',2)
```

If possible in SQL Server version you're using, always prefer cleaner way using native xquery to get data from XML, for example :

```
declare @Response varchar(max) = '
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <soap:Body>
            <RegisterUserResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
                <RegisterUserResult>DRnGXcT2gFTTxta4+ohnVx30Q1UL7N8gUqx0zpYMtMqmgwhkHmmXRWSoHu+Ghk0x</RegisterUserResult>
            </RegisterUserResponse>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>'

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES 
(
    DEFAULT 'http://tempuri.org/',
    'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as soap
)
SELECT CAST(@Response AS XML).value('(/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/RegisterUserResponse/RegisterUserResult)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
  as 'RegisterUserResult'
```

**<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/760)</kbd>**